# Trying to scrape forecast.weather.gov and having issues particularly with getting data from a WriteText tag

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
example = """writeText('<b>Sunday, January 26 at  1pm</b><br>Temperature: 41 &deg;F&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dewpoint: 34 &deg;F&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Wind Chill: 36 &deg;F&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Surface Wind: W 7mph<br>Sky Cover (%): 63%&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Precipitation Potential (%): 5%&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Relative Humidity (%): 76%<br>Rain: <10%&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Thunder: <10%&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Snow: <10%&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Freezing Rain: <10%&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sleet: <10%')

writeText('<b>Sunday, January 26 at  2pm</b><br>Temperature: 41 &deg;F&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dewpoint: 34 &deg;F&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Wind Chill: 36 &deg;F&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Surface Wind: W 7mph<br>Sky Cover (%): 62%&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Precipitation Potential (%): 5%&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Relative Humidity (%): 76%<br>Rain: <10%&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Thunder: <10%&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Snow: <10%&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Freezing Rain: <10%&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sleet: <10%')"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(example, "html.parser")
date = re.findall(r'<b>\s*(.*?)\s*</b>', str(soup))
print (date)
temp = re.findall(r'<br>\s*(.*?)\s*<&nbsp;', str(soup))
print(temp)
```

I want to extract the date, temperature, dewpoint, wind chill, and all the attributes till sleet. Could extract only the date!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if everything looks like your example, you don't need beautifulsoup and definitely not regex. Plain old string manipulation will do:

```
ex = example.replace('&nbsp;',' ').replace('&deg;','°')
ex2 = ex.split('     ')
for i in ex2:
    if '<br>' in i:
        print(i.split('<br>')[1])
    else:
        print(i)
```

Obviously, you can play with it a little more.

Output:

```
Temperature: 41 °F
Dewpoint: 34 °F
Wind Chill: 36 °F
Sky Cover (%): 63%
Precipitation Potential (%): 5%
Rain: <10%
Thunder: <10%
Snow: <10%
Freezing Rain: <10%
Temperature: 41 °F
Dewpoint: 34 °F
Wind Chill: 36 °F
Sky Cover (%): 62%
Precipitation Potential (%): 5%
Rain: <10%
Thunder: <10%
Snow: <10%
Freezing Rain: <10%
Sleet: <10%')
```